# Easy Way for Non-Nerd to Manage Simple Site?

Tags: web-services, web-hosting

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question for StackOverflow. I have a friend show wants a simple "Brochure Ware" web site. I could make it for him but it would be better if he could manage it himself. Are there any services out there that allow a non-technical person to create and maintain a very simple site? I'm thinking just a few pages - contact, about, home with some photos and general info. He also wants to sell some stuff but I'm going to suggest he does this using EBay but the web site would be a handy reference for potential customers who want to know more about him and his services.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers
Mark

Comment: try http://superuser.com

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_content_management_system is what you're looking for. Inside there're many links to CMS providers/software.

Comment: Thanks - I'll post on superuser too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agreed with the CMS comment @Phil Hunt

if you are a true non-nerd go for the 5 minute install of wordpress

so simple. Shopify plugin?

Comment: All the comments are good so difficult to pick an answer but Wordpress and Shopify seem to be some of the better options. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a [Content Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) (CMS).

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own software, try something open-source, or go the easy way, and go with SaaS: software as a service. Something that fits your needs (based on what you told us), is something like [Shopify](http://shopify.com). It manages your products, orders, but also has functionality to manage static pages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bjorn. Shopify does look like the sort of thing I'm after.